# How to remove woo-commerce themes default css ?

Tags: wordpress-theming

How to remove woo-commerce themes default css

like 
layout.css 
style.css
and other files

Answer (score 1):

You can disable WooCommerce default style sheets by adding the below code snippet to your theme's functions.php.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_enqueue_styles', '__return_false' );
```